# UIEdgeInsets only working for left side, not right

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

Quick question, so I am trying to get the cells of a tableView to be inset by a certain amount of pixels (15). However, when using UIEdgeInsets, only the left number seems to work. The right number does nothing. Any thoughts? Below is a screenshot and some of the relevant code being used.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
    tableView.separatorColor = .white
    //tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 242, g: 241, b: 246)
    //tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension

    navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleCancel))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleSave))
    
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 15)

    setupImageButton()
}
```

[image: Example of wrong inset]

Comment: You probably want to use `.layoutMargins` instead of `.contentInset` .... `tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 15, bottom: 0, right: 15)`